# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' using Sqlite: mis-configuration?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, driver

I'm running PHP 5.4.5 on Apache 2.2 on Windows XP.  Twice :-)  Both machines are set up, I think, identically, but one machine works fine while the other one generates the error.  (They're both development machines - one is for developing and the other is a quarantined tester)

I've got the extensions php_pdo.dll, php_pdo_sqlite.dll, and php_sqlite.dll all enabled (though of those, only php_pdo_sqlite.dll is in the ext directory, and pdo_sqlite.dll is actually called php_sqlite3.dll - but I understand that's all as it should be.).

If it helps, this fails at construction time.  I'm wrapping the PDO with a class of my own: the offending code looks like this:

class

```
ADO extends PDO {

    function __construct ($cnString = 'sqlite:..') {
        parent::__construct ($cnString);
        $this->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
...
```

but that doesn't explain what's happening, because, as I said, this works fine on the play machine.

I think I'm just going blind and can't see something obvious :-)  Any ideas, folks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php - Do you actually see sqlite there? If not, your issue is NOT in your code as-is, but in the PHP configuration.

Comment: Are the extensions listed as enabled in phpinfo?

Comment: pdo::getAvailableDrivers returns nothing.

Comment: No, the extensions are not listed in phpinfo.  I've just noticed something else odd: php lists the extension_dir as C:\php, but the ini file defines it as C:\PHP\ext.  It occurs to me to wonder whether I'm looking at a dud ini file: where does PHP find it?

Comment: ...later:  Nope, only one php.ini, right where it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!  I was right - it was obvious and I was going blind :-)

In Apache's httpd.conf, in the section marked #BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS... the PHPIniDir had been commented out.  No idea why, nothing to do with me.  Must have been an iffy install.  But, I decommented it, and all is now as it should be.

Wonder why PHP didn't complain that there was no ini file?  (There was nothing in the error log).  One to watch for in future, I think.

Thanks for the leading questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message after switching to a new PHP version.
The solution was simple but maybe posting it here might still help someone who ends up here through Google...

I still had to unescape the pdo_mysql / pdo_mysqlite extension in my php.ini file (depending on whether you are using mysql or myslq lite version)
So unescape these lines (take away the ;)

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```